# how to add button as menu item in Android?

Tags: android

i want to add an '`OK`' button in my apps `menu` as a `menu item`.
here is my manue file :

**code :**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:id="@+id/item1" 
          android:titleCondensed="Persist"
          android:title="Sahih International" 
          android:checkable="true"
 />

   <item android:id="@+id/item2" 
         android:titleCondensed="Persist"
         android:title="Muhsin Khan" 
         android:checkable="true" />

       <item android:id="@+id/item3" 
          android:titleCondensed="Persist"
          android:title="Pickthall" 
          android:checkable="true"
 />

   <item android:id="@+id/item4" 
         android:titleCondensed="Persist"
         android:title="Yusuf Ali" 
         android:checkable="true" />

       <item android:id="@+id/item5" 
          android:titleCondensed="Persist"
          android:title="Shakir" 
          android:checkable="true"
 />
</menu>
```

Comment: Menu items do indeed appear as buttons. Not sure what more you want.

Comment: Actually i want to select multiple items from my Context Menu and when i'll press OK button , that context menu should disappear. Is there any way to do That ??

Comment: And what part are you struggling with?

Comment: i think you can implement the same behaviour by implementing onOptionsItemSelected.

Comment: Just tell me one thing, how can i select multiple items in a Context menu ??? :\ @Love :*

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/OK"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="OK" />
```